# How can I get my Properties tab back in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I accidentally closed the Properties tab in Eclipse. I need this to do some Layout editing. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look in `Window >> Show View >> Properties`

Comment: You may also have to be in the "Debug" perspective too, which you can do by choosing "Window | Open Perspective | Other ... | Debug"

Answer (score 1):

Window > Show View > Others > General > Properties

Comment: I retracted my downvote but good luck getting rid of the others.

Answer (score 1):

Try "**window -> prespective -> reset prespective**" if the others suggestions did not work